# create root key in Windows registry

Tags: windows, registry

I want to know make sure if there is any way how to create a root key in Windows registry, I mean key on same level as HKEY_USERS. I was not able to find function in C# or C++ api for this (only subkeys) so I think this is not possible.

Thank you

Comment: The root registry Key on the local system is "\Registry". It's in the native object namespace root Directory. HKLM is a predefined pseudo-handle, which when used locally references the Key "\Registry\Machine". Likewise HKU references "\Registry\User", and HKCU references the current user's subkey. The predefined HKLM and HKU keys can also be used with `RegConnectRegistryW`, to access a remote system's registry. Functions in the Windows registry API map a predefined Key to a real Key handle.

Comment: You can only create subkeys via the Windows API because these functions always use the `RootDirectory` handle of the [`OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wudfwdm/ns-wudfwdm-_object_attributes) that's passed to a native registry function such as [`NtCreateKey`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwcreatekey). You'd have to use the native API to create a key in "\Registry", if that's even allowed. Either way, regedit won't show it since it populates the tree using the predefined handles.